# Search in another book VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search a range of cells previously selected on Excel in another book.

I have a list of ID's and Name on other book of Excel. I want to select a list o cells, search on the other excel and paste de cells searched in a range of cells on the columns I.

Example:

Search A1,A2, A3 and paste on I1,I2, I3.

```
     Sub Macro1()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="root....Libro3.xlsx"
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False).Activate
Range(Selection.Offset(0, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=[A5]
 End Sub
```

I tried with this, but just work for a column.

Comment: Are you searching the4 selected cell from the list of ID's and names?

Comment: No. For example, if in my Excel I have 4 ID's, I want to search the name of this ID's on the other Excel.

Comment: In your code you are selecting the entire sheet "Hoja1" and then using find to search for activecell, what is activecell.  I am just trying to understand your question.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.

I have a list of ID´s and Name on other Excel´s book.

I  have a principal Excel, who is taken  ID´s on one column named ID´s, A1, A2, A3, etc. I need to select all this ID´s, search on the other Excel and bring all its name to the column "I".

ID (A)                                                 Name (I)
101                                                    John Mary

Comment: Perhaps images of your data and desired outcome would help?